# Show that $\lim_{x\to 1} |x-1|/(x^2-1)$ does not exist.

Tags: real-analysis

I tried to use sequential definition but couldn't find two sequences s.t $\lim(x_n)= \lim(y_n)=1$ but $\lim(f(x_n))$ is not equal to $\lim(f(y_n))$. I guess it can be solved using just the definition. I am new to this so please help.

Answer (score 2):

Just take $x_n=1+\frac 1 n$ and $y_n=1-\frac  1 n$.  The limits are $2$ and $-2$.

Answer (score 0):

For $x>1$ we have $$\frac{x-1}{x^2-1}=\frac{x-1}{x-1)(x+1)}=\frac{1}{x+1}$$
and for $x<1$ we have $$\frac{-(x-1)}{(x-1)(x+1)}=-\frac{1}{x+1}$$,where domain is $\mathbb R-\{-1,1\}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

You can translate the argument and write the limit as

$$\lim_{y\to0}\frac{|y|}y\frac1{y+2}.$$

The second fraction tends to $2$ and is harmless. And the first is the problem.